# Using boost::bind with a constructor

Tags: c++, boost, constructor, bind

I'm trying to create new objects and add them to a list of objects using boost::bind.  For example.

```
struct Stuff {int some_member;};
struct Object{
    Object(int n);
};
....
list<Stuff> a;   
list<Object> objs;
....
transform(a.begin(),a.end(),back_inserter(objs), 
  boost::bind(Object,
     boost::bind(&Stuff::some_member,_1)
  )
);
```

This doesn't appear to work.  Is there any way to use a constructor with boost::bind, or should I try some other method?

Comment: What does you mean "appear to work"? it is not compiled or list isn't populated?

Comment: Som code that actually compiles would help. What is "a" - it appears to have collection begin & end methods but also some_member?

Comment: jon, that was an error on my part.  It's fixed now.  Dewfy, the code doesn't compile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `Stuff::some_member` is `int` and `Object` has a non-explicit ctor taking an `int`, this should work:

```
list<Stuff> a;   
list<Object> objs;
transform(a.begin(),a.end(),back_inserter(objs), 
  boost::bind(&Stuff::some_member,_1)
);
```

Otherwise, you could use [boost::lambda::constructor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/lambda/le_in_details.html#lambda.construction_and_destruction)

Comment: I simplified my code a little too much.  The constructor in my real code took three arguments, so in implicit conversion trick doesn't work.  The link answered my question completely though.  Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

If you are using boost 1.43, you can use boost::factory and boost::value_factory, which let you encapsulate a constructor invocation.
Like this:

```
 transform(a.begin(),a.end(),back_inserter(objs), 
  boost::bind(boost::value_factory<Object>(),
     boost::bind(&Stuff::some_member,_1)
  )
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Éric's link says, in part "It is not possible to take the address of a constructor, hence constructors cannot be used as target functions in bind expressions."  So what I was trying to do was impossible.

I got around it by creating a function:

```
Object Object_factory(int n)
{  return Object(n); }
```

and using Object_factory where I was trying to use the Object constructor.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what `a::some_member` is returning -- if it is an `Object` then you shouldn't need to wrap the result in an `Object` ctor -- it will have already been constructed. If the routine is not returning an `Object` then you're likely going to have to massage the result a bit, which you could pull of with `boost::bind` but a utility function may keep the code more readable.

In either case, more code would help, specifically the type instance of `a` and `Object`.

Comment: I changed the code a bit.  Lets say I have a Object(int) constructor and Stuff::some_member is an int.  Basically my question is, can anything of the form boost::bind(Object,...) ever work, or are constructors just not allowed as an argument to bind?